Change in price of underlying impact on delta gamma and vega
I am working my way through Natenberg's book as well as the accompanying workbook, and there is a question I cannot figure out (p86).

Futures price = 149.65
time to August expiration = 8 weeks
annual volatility = 24.20%

You have the following position:

-32 August 140 puts
+30 August 160 calls
-15 August futures contracts

with the options having these risk sensitivities



option
delta
gamma
theta
vega




Aug 140 put
-22.6
2.12
-.0381
.176


Aug 160 call
25.5
2.26
-.0407
.188



I correctly calculated that the greeks for my position were



delta
gamma
theta
vega




-11.8
-0.04
+0.0018
0.008



The question is
What will happen to your delta, gamma, and vega position if the futures price rises while all other market conditions remain unchanged?
The answers say that the delta, gamma, and vega would all become positive. I don't see how, with rising prices and negative gamma, even if its very small, the delta becomes positive. Why does the gamma and the vega become positive as well?
Would somebody please explain to me why this is the case?
Thank you in advance!

Without having done the maths myself - as you drift away from the short put strike towards the long call strike, your gamma also starts becoming more positive. This is because the future drifts away from the short put strike of 140 to being closer to the 160 long calls (atmf options habe more gamma than otm/itm options). This also naturally means that you start accruing deltas, as you drift.
The small -ve gamma that you calculate is only locally correct, gamma also changes with the level of the underlying with respect to the strikes of the portfolio. The vega becoming (more) positive has a similar rationale.
